# Sending push notification to Tizen server wierd error

Tags: push-notification, tizen

I have a strange error while trying to send push notifications to watches using tizen REST API.

I did an application to carry customer's SOS (inside nightclubs) and directly push it into watches.

The strange thing is that while I send push to dev apps the RQM server dosn't have a gateway link.

But on my prod watches I have to use the server "53" that contains a gateway part.

```
$idToUrlMap = [
        "00" => "https://useast.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "02" => "https://apsoutheast.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "03" => "https://euwest.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "04" => "https://apnortheast.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "05" => "https://apkorea.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "06" => "https://apchina.push.samsungosp.com.cn:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "50" => "https://useast.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "52" => "https://apsoutheast.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "53" => "https://euwest.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "54" => "https://apnortheast.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "55" => "https://apkorea.gateway.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push",
        "56" => "https://apchina.gateway.push.samsungosp.com.cn:8090/spp/pns/api/push"
    ];
```

When I trying to send a push to any link that contains "gateway", I get this error :

```
{"results":[{"regID":"","requestID":"","statusCode":1011,"statusMsg":"INVALID_REQUIRED_FIELD"}]}
```

But when I send to other servers that does not contain gateway I just get the error I have to (for example : `{"results":[{"regID":"blabla","requestID":"0000002","statusCode":3067,"statusMsg":"error of invalid serverId of regId"}]}`)

And all of my current 5 watches that I added are on the "53" server that contains a gateway.

Does anyone already have this problem ? Or has a suggestion ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The request manager (RQM) servers collect your push notifications before sending them to the applications. The RQM server must be chosen based on the first 2 digits of the registration ID.
For example, if the registration ID of the application that you want to send a notification to begins with 04, the URL of the RQM server must be https://apnortheast.push.samsungosp.com:8090/spp/pns/api/push.

so please choose RQM server accordingly.

Comment: Yes I use the good server provided by the first two chars of the regID but while the regID is > 50, you can't put multiples regID anymore into the request and it seems to be a bug by Tizen ..